# What does the word "Besides" means?

Tags: meaning

I have this sentence and I can't figure out what it means:

> For all types besides BN, RLE, LRE, RLO, LRO, and PDF: (do some work...)

Does that mean that I have to do the work for all the types including the ones that are listed or excluding them?

I looked up the word "Besides" in the dictionary and it says:

> preposition: in addition to; apart from.

Which doesn't help!

Here is the [link](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/tr9-23.html#X6) to the full text.

Comment: Every type other than BN ... PDF.

Comment: In the given context, *besides* means *apart from*, *except*.

Comment: Sadly, dictionaries aren't infallible. I won't be recommending CED in the near future.

Comment: This is posted to the wrong SE. Should be English Language Learners. Please re-read the scope of SE EL&U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary definition here isn't entirely inaccurate or useless; the usage that you provided as your example fits the second part of the defintion: "apart from". Your example is requiring that the work be done if the type is NOT any of the listed ones - in other words, "for all types **apart from** [list]: (Do the work)". It can also be expressed as "for all types **other than** [list]: (Do the work)". In a more formalised pseudocode-ish form, it can be expressed as an IF construct with a negated condition:

```
if type is not in [list] then
    (do the work)
end if
```

Comment: thanks, It would have been much easier if the article wrote the pseudocode in the first place since it is an algorithm related to other languages

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the word besides means apart from or you can say excluding. So  it says you have exclude these and not include.

Comment: But it *also* means "in addition to" or "as well as". Which means that those types would be included and not excluded.

Comment: Welcome to SE EL&U. If you had taken the introductory tour and read the help you would have seen that here we're looking for answers of sufficient length that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.